# Default Merge Commit message templates for all projects in group

Tags: git, git-commit

Is there a way to make a default merge commit message in all projects including the newly created ones in a group instead of manually changing it per project?

I want my default merge commit message to include my previous commit description/body.

```
Merge branch '%{source_branch}' into '%{target_branch}'

%{title} - %{description}

%{issues}

See merge request %{reference}
```

[Gitlab Commit message template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/commit_templates.html)
This link only tells me to do it by project.

Comment: The templates you're talking about are a *GitLab* feature, not a Git feature. Git does have `git commit -t` and `commit.template`, but the details are different. I'd also add that doing this sort of thing for a real merge is discouraged, though for a squash "merge" it's not only not discouraged, there's [`git-fmt-merge-msg`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fmt-merge-msg) to do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

A GitLab group can have [file templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#group-file-templates) and [Custom group-level project templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/custom_project_templates.html).

Try and [create a project from a built-in template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html#create-a-project-from-a-built-in-template) and see if you can define first that to include your `commit.template`.
But if not, that means those file templates do not include what you need (commit or merge request templates). In that case, they would need to be added on a project-by-project basis.